# function opens popup not before second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with magnific popup in a laravel environment and want both to be working together, so I wrote this:

[**Here's a fiddle with the problem**](http://jsfiddle.net/1kpdcvcy/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.image-popup-vertical-fit').on('click',function(){
    var image = $(this).attr('src');

    popnow(image);
});

    function popnow(a) {

    $('.image-popup-vertical-fit').magnificPopup({

        type: 'image',
        closeOnContentClick: true,
        mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
        image: {
            verticalFit: true
        },
        items: {
        src: a
            }

    });
}
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 margin-top-60">
    {{HTML::image('images/recentprojects1.png','recent',array('class' => 'img-responsive img-center image-popup-vertical-fit')) }}
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 margin-top-60" id="test">
    {{ HTML::image('images/pricing1.png','recent',array('class' => 'img-responsive img-center image-popup-vertical-fit')) }}
</div>
```

If I click on the popup-opening image for the first time after page reload nothing happens, if I click for the second time it opens.

But when I click on the first div for the first time after page reload and after that I click on the second, it still shows me the content of the first clicked div(on the first click on the second div - wrong image).

So it seems it doesn't take `var image` on every click. Is there something wrong with my function?

When I add `console.log(a)` to the top of `function popnow(a)`, the correct image src is logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have to iterate on each image and add magic's to each one. Then, you only have to click on each image to open the popup.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1kpdcvcy/1/)

```
function popnow(){
  $('.image-popup-vertical-fit').each(function(){
    var image = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).magnificPopup({

        type: 'image',
        closeOnContentClick: true,
        mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
        image: {
            verticalFit: true
        },
        items: {
            src: image
        }
      });
   });
}
 // Init function
  popnow();
```

PS: I've used the plugin from a CDN. When using jsfiddle, try to load your plugins or libraries from a CDN, not from the workspace.

Answer (score 1):

What `magnificPopup` does is to enable the popup. So first click you just enable it, not call it out.
Second click on second image pops up the first, is because you enable it with src set to the first image.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.image-popup-vertical-fit').each(function(i, el) {
        $(el).magnificPopup({
                type: 'image',
                closeOnContentClick: true,
                mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
                image: {
                  verticalFit: true
                },
                items: {src: $(el).attr('src')}
        });
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myst/1kpdcvcy/3/)

By the way, I placed the code after the magnificPopup plugin. It's better to load the plugin before your code to use it.